Uniform a variable value by other variables
Suppose I have the following:
data have;
  input ID $ (Start End) (:date.) Place $;
  format start end date9.;
cards;
0001 13JAN2015 20JAN2015 .
0001 13JAN2015 20JAN2015 1
0001 13JAN2015 20JAN2015 .
0001 21JAN2015 31DEC2015 .
0001 01JAN2018 31DEC2018 .
0001 01JAN2019 31DEC2019 .
0002 01JAN2015 31DEC2015 1
0002 01JAN2015 31DEC2015 .
0002 01JAN2015 31DEC2015 1
;


Is there a way to get the following?

data have1;
  input ID $ (Start End) (:date.) Place $;
  format start end date9.;
cards;
0001 13JAN2015 20JAN2015 1
0001 13JAN2015 20JAN2015 1
0001 13JAN2015 20JAN2015 1
0001 21JAN2015 31DEC2015 .
0001 01JAN2018 31DEC2018 .
0001 01JAN2019 31DEC2019 .
0002 01JAN2015 31DEC2015 1
0002 01JAN2015 31DEC2015 1
0002 01JAN2015 31DEC2015 1
;

In other words I need to uniform "Place" variable value = 1 by ID and Start-End.

Is Place really a character variable?

Assuming Place is numeric:
data have;
  input ID $ (Start End) (:date.) Place;
  format start end date9.;
cards;
0001 13JAN2015 20JAN2015 .
0001 13JAN2015 20JAN2015 1
0001 13JAN2015 20JAN2015 .
0001 21JAN2015 31DEC2015 .
0001 01JAN2018 31DEC2018 .
0001 01JAN2019 31DEC2019 .
0002 01JAN2015 31DEC2015 1
0002 01JAN2015 31DEC2015 .
0002 01JAN2015 31DEC2015 1
;

data want(drop = p);
   do until (last.End);
      set have;
      by ID Start End;
      if Place then p = 1;
   end;

   do until (last.End);
      set have;
      by ID Start End;
      Place = p;
      output;
   end;
run;

Result:
ID    Start      End        Place
0001  13JAN2015  20JAN2015  1
0001  13JAN2015  20JAN2015  1
0001  13JAN2015  20JAN2015  1
0001  21JAN2015  31DEC2015  .
0001  01JAN2018  31DEC2018  .
0001  01JAN2019  31DEC2019  .
0002  01JAN2015  31DEC2015  1
0002  01JAN2015  31DEC2015  1
0002  01JAN2015  31DEC2015  1


One option would be to use PROC TIMESERIES. Set all missing values within the group of id start end to the max value in the group.
proc timeseries data=have out=want(drop=time);
    by id start end;
    var place / setmissing=max;
run;

ID      Start       End         Place
0001    13JAN2015   20JAN2015   1
0001    13JAN2015   20JAN2015   1
0001    13JAN2015   20JAN2015   1
0001    21JAN2015   31DEC2015   .
0001    01JAN2018   31DEC2018   .
0001    01JAN2019   31DEC2019   .
0002    01JAN2015   31DEC2015   1
0002    01JAN2015   31DEC2015   1
0002    01JAN2015   31DEC2015   1


If the data are sorted by ID/START/END, then you could use the code below.  Of course, this assumes that if there are more than one instance of non-missing place for a given ID/START/END, they all have the same value.
data want;
  merge have (drop=place)
        have (where=(not missing(place)));
  by id beg end;
run;

If the data are grouped by ID/START/END, but not sorted:
data need/view=need;
  set have;
  by id beg end notsorted;
  if first.end then _grpnum+1;
run;
data want (drop=_:);
  merge need (drop=place)
        need (where=(not missing(place)));
  by _grpnum;
run;

The first data step is a data step view, and doesn't cause a separate pass through the data. It effectively defines a data "pipe" that is only actuated when used in the subsequent data step.
